# Why 1 is added to both actual and predicted value in RMSLE?

Tags: error, rms

Here is the formula of RMSLE (Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error)

[image]

Where X is predicted value and Y is actual value.

I wonder why the "1" addition to both predicted value and actual value?

On this [source](https://peltarion.com/knowledge-center/documentation/modeling-view/build-an-ai-model/loss-functions/mean-squared-logarithmic-error-(msle)), it is stated that "The reason ‘1’ is added to both x and y is for mathematical convenience since log(0) is not defined but both x or y can be 0." But what if x or y is -1?

Comment: If $y$ denotes actual house prices, it can't be negative. Also, if you train a regression model on a dataset where all (true) values of the target variable $y$ are positive, the predicted value $\hat{y}$ corresponding to a training datapoint is likely to be positive as well (although in some cases $\hat{y}$  can be negative too, so a better MSLE to avoid numerical errors could be $\sqrt(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(log(\hat{y_i}+c)-log(y_i+c))^2)$, where $c=\epsilon-\min \limits_{i} (\hat{y_i})$ for some $\epsilon>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot take logarithms of negative numbers, presumably $x$ in this case can take such values that $x+1 > 0$, same goes for $y$. Otherwise this trick wouldn’t work.